# Flutter app not connecting with FastApi using http package

Tags: flutter, fastapi

I am trying to use Flutter to fetch data from my custom api made with FastApi.

Here is my python code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
import datetime

app = FastAPI()

class TextModel(BaseModel):
    input_text: str
    model: str
    min_length: int = 40
    max_length: int = 80

@app.post(f"/post_input/")
async def receive_long_text(input: TextModel):

    summary = "Message recieved!"
    print(summary)
    return {"output_text": summary}
```

Here is my flutter code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myapp/screens/signup.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override

  Future<void> sendLongText(String input_text) async {
    const url = 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/post_input/';
    print('res start');
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      // body: {}
      body: jsonEncode({
        'input_text': input_text,
        'model': 'T5',
        'min_length': 40,
        'max_length': 80
      })
    );
    print(response);
    print('res end');
  }

  void fetchApi(String s) async {
    sendLongText(s);
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String s = "The tortoise, a reptile of the Testudinidae family, is a fascinating creature with many unique features and adaptations that allow it to thrive in a variety of environments. In this essay, we will explore the physical characteristics, behavior, habitat, and conservation status of the tortoise. The first thing that comes to mind when one thinks of a tortoise is its shell. The shell of a tortoise is made up of two parts: the carapace, which covers the back, and the plastron, which covers the underside. The shell is made up of bone and is covered by scutes, which are thick, bony plates that protect the tortoise from predators and the environment. The shape and size of the shell can vary greatly depending on the species, with some tortoises having streamlined shells for faster movement, and others having dome-shaped shells for protection.";

    return Material(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            const Center(child: Text("Welcome to home page")),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => fetchApi(s),
                  child: const Text('Send'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am running my Flutter app on my physical device, and it has internet permission given.

But, when I click on 'Send' button in my Flutter app, it shows: "Unhandled Exception: Connection timed out", after waiting for some time, and my Api does not record any request(btw, the Api work fine on web (http://127.0.0.0.1:8000/post_input).

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71195390/my-flutter-app-fails-to-connect-to-fastapi), I tried running:

```
uvicorn main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0
```

instead of just:

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

And used my local IP here:

```
 Future<void> sendLongText(String input_text) async {
    const url = 'http://192.168.x.x:8000/post_input/';
```

I am getting an error: Unhandled Exception: Connection refused

Comment: Is it `192.168.x.x` in your actual code? You're supposed to replace the `x.x` with the address of your local PC.

Comment: No. I am using the complete IP address in my actual code. I just used .x.x here.